# Kotlin Collection indexOf using reference equality ===

Tags: kotlin, collections

In Kotlin, `indexOf(x)` called on a `Collection` returns the index of the first element  that `equals(x)` (structural equality `==`)

How can one get the index based on referential equality (`===`) instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution to this would be to use `indexOfFirst`:

```kotlin
data class Person(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: Int
)

val targetPerson = Person("Greg", "Grimaldus", 47)

val people = listOf(
    Person("Tabitha", "Thimblewort", 38),

    Person("Shawn", "Been", 27),

    // not this one
    Person("Greg", "Grimaldus", 47),

    // this one
    targetPerson
)

people.indexOfFirst { it === targetPerson }
```

The same can be done with any `Collection`, but be aware if the `Collection` in use is a `Set` your desired element may not be present since `Set`s use `.equals()` to eliminate duplicate elements.